# How can I recover data from a five disk raid 5 on HP Proliant DL 380

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hard-drive, raid5, sas, disaster-recovery

How can I recover data from a five disk RAID 5 on HP Proliant DL 380 where four of the five disks are reporting a SMART error. I have some critical data on the failed logical drive and checking online all I am getting is that the data is lost.

Comment: Ummm... rebuild the array and restore the data from backup?

Comment: I am very sorry for your data. Sometimes, data recovery specialists can do something (even on failed arrays), but in most cases it's a bit pricey.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your data *is* lost. A RAID 5 can only tolerate one drive failure. If four drives failed, there is nothing left to do but replace them and restore from backup.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the reply. I kind of understood that was the case but i was simply hoping for a hail mary especially because we have unfortunately not taken a backup and the partition contained the VHD for some VMs. Unforgivable I know! My concern now is how it could have been possible for four disks to fail at the same time.

Comment: Probably all of the disks were already failing for quite some time before now. I would not be surprised if the fifth disk were also near to failure. This is to be expected with ancient hardware.